# reactjs: Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs

The error happens in this part:

```
const {playing, bannerOpen} = useSelector(state => state.musicReducer);
```

I have searched for information, but I cannot fix it.
Apparently I only get that error in that part, I am a newbie and there are things that I do
not understand yet.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "../components/Theme";
import AddMusic from "../fragment/AddMusic";
import BottomNavigationMobile from "../fragment/BottomNavigationMobile";
import CurrentPlayingLarge from "../fragment/CurrentPlayingLarge";
import FooterMusicPlayer from "../fragment/FooterMusic";
import FooterSelectMusic from "../fragment/FooterSelectMusic";
import MobileTopNavigation from "../fragment/MobileTopNavigation";
import MusicCardContainer from "../fragment/MusicCardContainer";
import Navigation from "../fragment/Navigation";
import Playlist from "../fragment/Playlist";
import SideBar from "../fragment/SideBar";
import About from "./About";
import './css/Home.scss';
import Profile from "./Profile";
import Search from "./Search";
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

function getCurrPage(pathName) {
  switch (pathName) {
    case "/home":
        return <MusicCardContainer/>
    case "/home/search":
        return <Search/>
    case "/home/profile":
        return <Profile/>
    case "/home/add":
        return <AddMusic/>
    case "/home/about":
        return <About/>
    default:
        if (pathName.startsWith("/home/playlist/")){
            return <Playlist/>
        }
        return null
}
}

function Home() {

    const [screenSize, setScreenSize] = useState(undefined);
    const [currMusic, setCurrMusic] = useState(null);
    const [Page, setCurrPage] = useState(<MusicCardContainer/>);

    let pathname = window.location.pathname;
    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrPage(getCurrPage(pathname))
    }, [pathname]);

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    function handleResize() {
        setScreenSize(window.innerWidth);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        handleResize();
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    });

    const useStyle = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const {playing, bannerOpen} = useSelector(state => state.musicReducer);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrMusic(playing)
    }, [playing])

    return (
        <div style={useStyle.component} className={"home-container"}>
            {
                screenSize <= 970 ?
                    <MobileTopNavigation/> :
                    <Navigation/>
            }
            <section className={"home-music-container"}>
                <div className="sidebar-home">
                    <SideBar/>
                </div>
                <div className="main-home">
                    {
                        Page
                    }
                </div>
            </section>
            {
                bannerOpen
                &&
                <section className="current-large-banner">
                    <CurrentPlayingLarge/>
                </section>
            }
            <React.Fragment>
                {
                    currMusic
                        ?
                        <FooterMusicPlayer music={currMusic}/>
                        :
                        <FooterSelectMusic/>
                }
                {
                    screenSize <= 970 && <BottomNavigationMobile/>
                }
            </React.Fragment>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more context, like the HTML where it's used, for someone to be able to help you.